# Apply two condititions per Group of rows but if the first condition is satisfied dont check for the second condition and move to the Group [pyspark]

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following spark Dataframe

```py
data = [
    ("1", "SAP", "A", 1, 51.55, "Team1"),
    ("2", "SAP", "B", 1, 51.55, "Team1"),
    ("3", "SAP", "B", 1, 51.55, "Team1"),
    ("4", "SAP", "A", 1, 55.35, "Team2"),
    ("5", "SAP", "B", 1, 55.35, "Team2"),
    ("6", "SAP", "C", 1, 58.00, "Team3"),
    ("7", "SAP", "D", 1, 47.00, "Team3")
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "Source", "Type", "Active", "Weight", "Group"])
```

I want to apply the following two conditions per "Group", thus separately for the records of "Team1", "Team2" and "Team3"

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

condition1 = (F.col("Type") == "A") & (F.col("Active") == 1) & (F.col("Source") == "SAP")
condition2 = (F.col("Rank") == 1)

mainRecordWindow = Window.partitionBy("Group").orderBy(F.col("Weight").desc())
df = df.withColumn(
    "Rank", F.rank().over(mainRecordWindow)
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "main_record",
    F.when(condition1, 1).otherwise(F.when(condition2, 1).otherwise(0))
)

df.show()
```

The result is the following table:

```
+--+------+----+-------------+-----+----+-----------+
|ID|Source|Type|Active|Weight|Group|Rank|main_record|
+--+------+----+-------------+-----+----+-----------+
| 1|   SAP|   A|     1| 51.55|Team1|   1|          1|
| 2|   SAP|   B|     1| 51.55|Team1|   1|          1|
| 3|   SAP|   B|     1| 51.55|Team1|   1|          1|
| 4|   SAP|   A|     1| 55.35|Team2|   1|          1|
| 5|   SAP|   B|     1| 55.35|Team2|   1|          1|
| 6|   SAP|   C|     1| 58.00|Team3|   1|          1|
| 7|   SAP|   D|     1| 47.00|Team3|   2|          0|
+--+------+----+-------------+-----+----+-----------+
```

For records of "Team1", even though they satisfy the second condition, since the group has a already a row that satisfies the first condition (row with ID=1) then the other records should be marked as 0 for the main_record column for the same "Team".

The expected result should be:

```
+--+------+----+-------------+-----+----+-----------+
|ID|Source|Type|Active|Weight|Group|Rank|main_record|
+--+------+----+-------------+-----+----+-----------+
| 1|   SAP|   A|     1| 51.55|Team1|   1|          1|
| 2|   SAP|   B|     1| 51.55|Team1|   1|          0|
| 3|   SAP|   B|     1| 51.55|Team1|   1|          0|
| 4|   SAP|   A|     1| 55.35|Team2|   1|          1|
| 5|   SAP|   B|     1| 55.35|Team2|   1|          0|
| 6|   SAP|   C|     1| 58.00|Team3|   1|          1|
| 7|   SAP|   D|     1| 47.00|Team3|   2|          0|
+--+------+----+-------------+-----+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after working on it on

```py
import os
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
data = [
    ("1", "SAP", "A", 1, 51.55, "Team1"),
    ("2", "SAP", "B", 1, 51.55, "Team1"),
    ("3", "SAP", "B", 1, 51.55, "Team1"),
    ("4", "SAP", "A", 1, 55.35, "Team2"),
    ("5", "SAP", "B", 1, 55.35, "Team2"),
    ("6", "SAP", "C", 1, 58.00, "Team3"),
    ("7", "SAP", "D", 1, 47.00, "Team3")
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "Source", "Type", "Active", "Weight", "Group"])

condition1 = (F.col("Type") == "A") & (F.col("Active") == 1) & (F.col("Source") == "SAP")
condition2 = (F.col("Rank") == 1)
mainRecordWindow = Window.partitionBy("Group").orderBy(F.col("Weight").desc())
df_rank = df.withColumn("Rank", F.rank().over(mainRecordWindow))
df_rule1 = df_rank.withColumn("rule1_mr",F.when(condition1, 1).otherwise(0).cast("int"))
df_rule1.show()
df_rule1_group = df_rule1.groupBy("Group").agg(F.sum("rule1_mr").alias("sum"))
df_rule1_group.show()
rule2_groups_array = [row.Group for row in df_rule1_group.filter(F.col("sum") == 0).collect()]
print(rule2_groups_array)
df_rule2 = df_rule1.withColumn("rule2_mr", F.when(F.col("Group").isin(rule2_groups_array) & condition2, 1).otherwise(0).cast("int"))
df_rule2.show()
df_rule_concat = df_rule2.withColumn("main_record", (F.col("rule1_mr") + F.col("rule2_mr")).cast("int"))
df_rule_concat.show().
```

Briefly, I apply the first rule/condition. Then I create a second dataframe where I `sum()` the values of the first rule per `Group`. Then I create a list with the *Groups* that I should apply the second rule. And finally, I concatenate the two columns into 1 by adding the subsequent values from the application of the two conditions.

#### Result

```
+---+------+----+------+------+-----+----+--------+--------+-----------+
| ID|Source|Type|Active|Weight|Group|Rank|rule1_mr|rule2_mr|main_record|
+---+------+----+------+------+-----+----+--------+--------+-----------+
|  1|   SAP|   A|     1| 51.55|Team1|   1|       1|       0|          1|
|  2|   SAP|   B|     1| 51.55|Team1|   1|       0|       0|          0|
|  3|   SAP|   B|     1| 51.55|Team1|   1|       0|       0|          0|
|  4|   SAP|   A|     1| 55.35|Team2|   1|       1|       0|          1|
|  5|   SAP|   B|     1| 55.35|Team2|   1|       0|       0|          0|
|  6|   SAP|   C|     1|  58.0|Team3|   1|       0|       1|          1|
|  7|   SAP|   D|     1|  47.0|Team3|   2|       0|       0|          0|
+---+------+----+------+------+-----+----+--------+--------+-----------+
```